# Printing all variables starting with foo in zsh

Tags: zsh

In bash:

```
foo_a=1
foo_b=2
declare -p ${!foo_*}
```

Outputs:

```
declare -- foo_a="1"
declare -- foo_b="2"
```

How do I do this in *zsh*?

Why won't pasting the above into *zsh* fail to even set the variables?
It appears as if pasting a piece of code has no effect whatsoever unless all of the pasted code succeds? What's up with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. How to print all parameters starting with `foo`:

   ```
   declare -p ${(Mk)parameters:#foo*}
   ```

   All variables are stored in the `parameters` associative array, so it is enough to print all its keys `(k)` and search for pattern `foo*`. The flag `(M)` is present to remove non-matching elements.

   Output:

   ```
   typeset foo_a=1
   typeset foo_b=2
   ```

   (notice that `declare` is the same as `typeset`).

---

2. Pasting doesn't work as expected because of recently introduced feature called *bracketed_paste*:

   > zle_bracketed_paste
   >
   > Many terminal emulators have a feature that allows applications  to  identify
   >                 when  text  is pasted into the terminal rather than being typed normally. For
   >                 ZLE, this means that special characters such as  tabs  and  newlines  can  be
   >                 inserted instead of invoking editor commands.  Furthermore, pasted text forms
   >                 a single undo event and if the region is active, pasted text will replace the
   >                 region.
   >
   > This  two-element  array  contains the terminal escape sequences for enabling
   >                 and disabling the feature. These escape sequences are used to  enable  bracketed  paste  when ZLE is active and disable it at other times.  Unsetting the
   >                 parameter has the effect of ensuring that bracketed paste remains disabled.

   Just unset if you don't like it:

   ```
   unset zle_bracketed_paste
   ```

Answer (score 1):

@jimmij gave a great answer, and that works in the general case for printing the matches to the pattern for each key in an associative array.

In the case of `zsh` environment variables, however, there's a built-in solution I found using the `typeset` command when I was reading `man zshbuiltins`.

You can just use `typeset`'s `-m` option, and supply **in quotes** the pattern of parameter names you are trying to match.

### Printing Environment Variables Matching a Pattern

- Just the variable name:

  ```bsh
  typeset +m 'foo*'
  ```

  ```
  foo
  foo_fighters
  food
  ```
- Variable name and assigned value:

  ```bsh
  typeset -m 'foo*'
  ```

  ```
  foo=bar
  foo_fighters=awesome
  food=(my life)
  ```
- Typeset flags, variable name, and assigned value

  ```bsh
  typeset -p -m 'foo*'
  ```

  ```
  typeset foo=bar
  typeset foo_fighters=awesome
  typeset -a food=( my life )
  ```